# A naive question on the "continuously" degenerate ground states of 1d phonons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, symmetry-breaking, phonons, ground-state

In general, the gapless Goldstone mode is related to the "continuously" degenerate ground states. The Mexican hat potential is an example (see the logo of this SE website), where the bottom circle is the continuous ground-state manifold. Another example is the ferromagnetic (FM) states of the FM Heisenberg model, where the continuous ground-state manifold is the 2d sphere corresponding to the *global* rotation of spin directions.

All the above examples have a classical picture: The ground-state manifold or "continuously" degenerate ground states related by the continuous symmetry transformations.

**My question is:** Is there also a classical picture of "ground-state manifold" of the 1d oscillating atoms (phonons)? As we know, **under periodic boundary conditions and in the large size limit**, the excitation spectrum of phonons is **gapless** which is an example of Goldstone theorem.

**Edit:**

I think I made a **wrong statement** in my comments below: "It seems that the phonon vacuum state does NOT break any symmetry".

In fact, the phonon vacuum state (one of the degenerate ground states) **breaks** the global continuous translation symmetry, no matter the system size is *finite* or *infinite*.

Thus, it seems that there always exist both "spontaneously breaking of the continuous translation symmetry" and "continuously degenerate ground states", even when the system size is *finite*. But the **gapless excitation** can only happen when the system size is *infinite* (since the momentum $k$ is *discrete* when the system size is *finite*).

Therefore, the Goldstone theorem is a theorem for the *infinite* system ?? And how to intuitively understand the relation between "infinite size" and "gaplessness" without looking in the momentum space??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your language, the ground state manifold for 1d phonons is just R: uniform displacement of all atoms.

Comment: @Meng Cheng Thanks for your comment. What I'm not sure is:If we let $T(x), x\in R$ represent the global-translation operator, any translation-breaking ground state $\psi(x)$ in the manifold should be written as the form $\psi(x)=T(x)\psi(0)$ (correct me if I'm wrong), but I don't know how to define $\psi(0)$? It seems that the phonon vacuum state does NOT break any symmetry (correct me if I'm wrong) and thus can't be $\psi(0)$...

Comment: I don't really see how 1d phonon of oscillating atoms is different from 1d rotors. For atoms, you have a displacement field $u_n$ for each $n$, and the Hamiltonian contains terms like $(u_{n+1}-u_n)^2$, so it is invariant under a global shift $u_n\rightarrow u_n + a$ where $a\in R$. The presence of these atoms (i.e. the lattice) breaks the (continuous) translation symmetry. For 1D rotors, there is a U(1) angular variable $\theta_n$, and a simple Hamiltonian could be $\cos(\theta_n-\theta_{n+1})$, which is invariant under a global rotation $\theta_n\rightarrow \theta_n+\alpha$.

Comment: The ground state of rotors, say $\theta_n=0$, breaks the global U(1) rotation. Similarly, the ground state of the atoms, say $u_n=0$, breaks the continuous translation symmetry if you want to make the analogy.

Comment: @Meng Cheng  I get it, thanks for your clear explanations.

Comment: Any gapless system, be it Goldstone modes or Fermi sea, has finite size gap due to momentum discretization. True gaplessness only happens in thermodynamic limit. There is nothing special about Goldstone modes here. The special thing about spontaneous symmetry breaking in a finite size system is that besides Goldstone modes, there is also "tower of states" whose level spacing is 1/Volume which is much smaller than the Goldstone mode level spacing 1/L in dimensions > 1.

Comment: @Meng Cheng Thanks. I'm thinking that whether the "momentum (discretization)" is essential for the "gap" or "gaplessness ". For example, if we take the **open boundary condition** (OBC) for 1d atoms, then "momentum" is not a good quantum number anymore, but it seems that the continuous translation symmetry is still *spontaneously* broken (am I right?). Thus, there should still exist gapless Goldstone mode in the thermodynamic limit under OBC (am I right?). And what about the "tower of states"? 感谢程蒙学长的耐心解答。

Comment: Well, the boundary explicitly breaks translation symmetry, so technically this is not a good example. In fact, if you have translation symmetry momentum must be a good quantum number. Once you take the thermodynamic limit, the effect of OBC on the spectrum/correlation function becomes negligible if you look at the bulk away from the boundary.

Comment: @Meng Cheng Please allow me to give a little more clarification: OBC indeed explicitly breaks the **discrete lattice** translation symmetry($u_n\rightarrow u_{n+1}$), but does OBC also explicitly break the **continuous** translation symmetry($u_n\rightarrow u_n+a,a\in R$)? Anyway, your nice explanations have already made me clear, thank you all the same.